# Loop though Select attributed return an extra column?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to list all contrains that fulfills an criteria and then drop them,

```
DO $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r in  SELECT
                conrelid::regclass,
                conname
            FROM
                pg_constraint
            WHERE
                contype IN ('u')
                AND connamespace = 'public'::regnamespace
                AND conname ~* '_key'
  LOOP
     EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE % DROP CONSTRAINT %',r.conrelid, r.conname;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
```

When I execute this I get

```
ERROR:  query "SELECT 'ALTER TABLE % DROP CONSTRAINT %',r.conrelid, r.conname" returned 3 columns
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 14 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 42601
```

Why is 3 columns returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass identifiers like that to a dynamic SQL. Use `format()` instead:

```
EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %I DROP CONSTRAINT %I', r.conrelid::text, r.conname::text);
```